# Is there a way to set network proxy system-wide?

Tags: networking, http-proxy

If I want to have GNOME applications (as well as Firefox and Chrome) access the network through a proxy, I need only use **`gnome-network-properties`** (a nice and simple GUI I must say). For other apps (e.g. APT, Transmission, XChat), I have to use their specific ways of doing it.

Is there a way to avoid this, something I can turn on and off when in a network that requires a proxy (hostname:port)?

Comment: I think that the `http_proxy` variable is what you're looking for. Take a look in the [Proxy Support](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1575) howto.

Comment: I do believe a VPN is the best solution. It is straight forward and realistic. A VPN acts as a relay which is what the network will want.

Comment: Same question on
[Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9517/is-there-a-way-to-set-network-proxy-system-wide)
(contains solution on tsocks, tun2socks, proxyman),
[SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/361690/applying-proxy-settings-system-wide-on-linux),
[AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1297618/is-there-any-way-to-set-a-global-proxy-in-linux-which-works-across-all-apps).

Answer (score 12):

I think pretty much all linux/unix software that uses networking will honor the `http_proxy` and `ftp_proxy` environment variables. Depending on how your distribution is set up, `/etc/environment` will exist and be read by default by login shells.

You can add a line saying

`http_proxy=123.45.67.89:1011`

in `/etc/environment` easily enough, but changes in that file will only take hold the next time you start a shell process -- and *only* in that shell process. I don't think you *can* modify global variables in a shell other than your current one.

Comment: ... with the notable exception of Firefox and Thunderbird https://askubuntu.com/a/23123

Comment: and it appears, `node` [doesnt either](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18586902/26510)

Comment: yes, and reloading the shell in other words means a log out and then log in again for graphical shells.

Answer (score 7):

I agree that the best way to use the proxy server is with the environment variable `http_proxy`, as other answers have pointed out.  Unfortunately, not all applications honour the http_proxy environment variable, which is why I still use [tsocks](http://tsocks.sourceforge.net/about.php) for some programs to use LD_PRELOAD to force network connections to go through a SOCKS proxy.

Answer (score 4):

There's no one-for-all solution. Each program uses its own way to connect to a proxy server.

I have a similar problem at my office. I found that best way to do this is to use a VPN connection. When you connect, the whole system network traffic will go through the VPN. If you don't have access to a VPN server, you can run a new one manually, and connect it to the proxy server you've got.

If you have an application that doesn't support proxy, you can use something like *socksify*, to wrap its network connection.

Comment: So you've tried [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9517/is-there-a-way-to-set-network-proxy-system-wide/9519#9519) and failed?

Answer (score 4):

Besides [tsocks](http://tsocks.sourceforge.net/about.php) — which still AFAICT requires you to launch programs with the correct environment to work — you should check out [tun2socks](https://github.com/ambrop72/badvpn). With it you set up a TUN interface (i.e. a new network interface, just like a VPN would create) and any packets sent there get proxied to your SOCKS5 server. You then set up your system routes to actually send the traffic to this. Seems like a nice approach.

(I also found [redsocks](https://github.com/darkk/redsocks) via [this post](http://www.mblondel.org/journal/2011/06/27/transparent-system-wide-proxy/). This doesn't seem as elegant as using a TUN interface to me — e.g. it doesn't really handle UDP at all, for starters.)

Answer (score 4):

I use [this tool](https://github.com/himanshub16/ProxyMan/), which is basically a couple of scripts to configure settings for different applications from single point.

PS: I wrote and maintain that tool.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me
`vi /etc/environment`:

```
http_proxy="http://username:password@proxysrv:8080/"
https_proxy="https://username:password@proxysrv:8080/"
ftp_proxy="ftp://username:password@proxysrv:8080/"
no_proxy=".mylan.local,.domain1.com,host1,host2"
```

also
`vi /etc/yum.conf`:

```
proxy=http://proxysrv:8080
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue, but for me to accomplish a system wide proxy will be addressing Linux's kernel `iptables`. Adding and removing forwarding rules in the `iptables` (specific addresses,ports & protocols), acting on the network layer is the only way to ensure a system wide proxy, that can't be overridden by any app-specific settings in the application layer.

Answer (score 0):

In addtion to Shawn Jones resolution,

theres also a CHEATY lazy solution

> http_proxy="http://username:password@proxysrv:8080/"
> https_proxy=$http_proxy

if you need to setup also for the other it will only be required to write once.